# Yet another - Regular expression to match text that *doesn't* contain a word

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have an input like the following, where there are two script tags, and the 2nd script tag has src attribute, wherein I need to check if `wrapperId={wrapper_id}` is present -

```
<script type="text/javascript"> var blah; </script><script id="bleh" type="text/javascript" src="//domain/test.js?siteid=270606&testmode=0&banner360=1&banner=0&placementid=0&tp=3&wrapperId={wrapper_id}" > </script>
```

Following is the regex I have prepared so far -

```
<script(.*?)(?!<\/script>)(.*?)wrapperId={wrapper_id}(.*?)<\/script>
```

I am trying to match the script tag which **does not** contain a closing script tag (`</script>`).

However, if I run it at https://regex101.com/r/oZ2jL6/1, I see it matching the 1st script tag.

If I use PHP preg_match(), the result also says that match was found, but I am sure it is matching the 1st script tag, which I don't want.

Already checked related question -

[Regular expression to match a line that doesn't contain a word?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-text-that-doesnt-contain-a-word?rq=1)

Comment: I would recommend using a xml parser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am trying to match the script tag which does not contain a closing script tag ().

In your example you have a closing tag. Regular expressions for matching html are usually not a good idea. Regular expressions for invalid HTML are going to give you headaches.

Assuming a closing tag like your example try:

```
<script(.*?)<\/script><script(.*?)wrapperId={wrapper_id}(.*?)<\/script>
```